# Revoke CREATE STAGE privilege on a snowflake role

Tags: permissions, authorization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, snowflake-schema

I setup a new role called 'TEST_CLIENT_ROLE' and Granted `USAGE` and `CREATE SCHEMA` on a database called `TEST_CLIENT_DB`. I didnt grant any explicit permissions to `CREATE STAGE` on this database or schema. But still user belonging to the role is able to create stage.

I also explicitly revoke `CREATE STAGE` on the role like below

```
REVOKE CREATE STAGE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_CLIENT_DB FROM ROLE TEST_CLIENT_ROLE;
REVOKE CREATE STAGE ON FUTURE SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST_CLIENT_DB FROM ROLE TEST_CLIENT_ROLE;
```

But still the user in that role is able to create stage under that database schema.

Can someone help me out in figuring how to make sure that a role cant create stage under a database/schema

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake roles inherit permissions from child roles. If this role is the parent of another role with this permission, you need to revoke the permission from the child role. Also, object owners have pretty much full permissions so if the role is the owner, I don't think you can revoke the permission

Comment: The role doesn't inherit from any other role I believe. But what I observed is if the role is granted create schema privilege then the role is able to create stage too.

Comment: I think I understood now if a role create a schema then it has full ownership of that schema and object under it. So cant revoke the permissions.

Comment: Yeah if the role created the schema, I don't think you can revoke any permissions that are granted to it by virtue of being the owner